# hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK vs. hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter

Tags: theming, hooks

Let's say some people are working on a contrib module ([link](https://www.drupal.org/project/twigsuggest)) to provide some obvious template suggestions which are not covered by the default [Twig Template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions). View mode for fields, region for blocks etc.

Out of habit I'd use [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x). I simply add my suggestions following some logic, done.

> This hook allows any module or theme to provide alternative theme
>   function or template name suggestions and *reorder* or *remove*
>   suggestions provided by `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()` or by earlier
>   invocations of this hook.

Then I see there's [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8.2.x) which more or less does the same except for *reordering* or *removing* suggestions. But basically looking at its description it does *exactly* what that contrib module is supposed to do.

> This hook allows modules to provide alternative theme function or
>   template name suggestions.

And now I'm wondering which one of these hooks should be used at best? Is it totally up to us? Do there arise any disadvantages of using the `*_alter` hook? Do we better use the mere suggestion `*_HOOK` to allow other modules to intervene later in the process?

Comment: The linked module should try to add suggestions in hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK as long as it doesn't depend itself on existing suggestions, so that other modules still have the option to override these suggestions in an alter hook.

Comment: @4k4 – To use the `*_alter` hook really only when I *alter* existing suggestions in the sense of changing them to something different? Like so?

Comment: Hooks don't have priorities, so having two hooks, one main hook and one alter tries to compensate this. Like having a priority system with only two levels. So if you add something on the second level there is no third level for other modules, unless they resort to unusual solutions like module weights.

Comment: @4k4 – Would you mind making that a canonical answer? As I see `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` to be recommended pretty often for simply adding new suggestions. At least I did recommend it on some few upvoted and accepted answers. Which I will update.

Comment: Don't think you need to update if the answers are for custom modules. The contrib module in the question is different, because it adds more general suggestions which others might want to alter in their custom modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked module should try to add suggestions in `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK` as long as it doesn't depend itself on existing suggestions, so that other modules still have the option to override these suggestions in an alter hook.

Hooks don't have priorities, which having two hooks, one main and one alter hook, is trying to compensate. This is like a priority system with only two levels. If you add something on the second level there is no third level for other modules, unless they resort to unusual solutions like module weights.

Comment: Hooks do have priorities, and alter hooks are executed after the other hooks. It's not possible to execute hooks after the equivalent alter hooks.